# Multiple Kubernetes pods as consumers of a Amazon SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, publish-subscribe

I have a `Deployment` YAML that will launch a pod as part of event driven architecture. Due to scale out or in events, it is not in known in advance how many pods will be running at any point in time. My plan is to implement pods as subscribers of an SNS topic or SQS queue. But, I am not sure if SNS-SQS combination is the right way to implement pub-sub with pods in a Kubernetes cluster.

1. An SNS topic can [only be subscribed](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simplify-pubsub-messaging-with-amazon-sns-message-filtering/) by a SQS queue, Lambda function or an HTTP endpoint. Even if I exposed an HTTP endpoint from my container image, the HTTP endpoint cannot be known in advance because each pod will get a different id and an IP address. It is for this purpose the `Service` object exists. However, the `Service` object will act only as a load balancer for the scaled-out pods. In other words, the messages wouldn't flow to each and every pod.
2. I cannot have my pod subscribed to a SQS queue, that is subscribed to a SNS topic, because every message that is read by consumer must be deleted by the consumer. Otherwise, the message might be read again by the (same) consumer and my application will have to be coded for handling idempotency - too much overhead! Even if the application deletes the message, other pods (that would have scaled out) won't get the message.

Can you please help confirm my understanding?

Comment: Can you use an open-source event bus or message-queue system, like Kafka or RabbitMQ?  You do in general probably need some consideration of duplicate messages occurring; consider the possibility of a worker accepting a message, doing all of the work, but then failing ("the node loses power") just before it's able to send the acknowledgement back to the messaging system.

Comment: I wanted to be clear that SNS/SQS is/is not a good choice. I might end up using ActiveMQ.